# how to change kubernetes server port?

Tags: kubernetes

I want to change the Kubernetes server endpoint port. 
I am currently using port `6443` and would like to change it to port `7443`.

Kubernetes is installed on-premises and is a single master node.

Answer (score 1):

You can change the default secure port by passing the `--secure-port` flag when you start your k8s api server.

Checkout the next links for more:

https://kubernetes.io/docs/reference/access-authn-authz/controlling-access/#api-server-ports-and-ips

https://kubernetes.io/docs/reference/command-line-tools-reference/kube-apiserver/